# Web application with App_code to web service

Tags: c#, web-services, web-applications, app-code

I have a folder app_code that has my business logic and DAL, what I am trying to do is put classes from the app_code folder to a web service ? what is the recommended route ? I need some guidance on what technology should be used.
Thank you

Comment: Create a Class Library project, migrate your code to it.  Reference the new library project in your existing code and your new project. That is the basic code re-use approach -- class libraries. Of course, if your current code is too coupled to the existing project -- this might not be easy.

Comment: I have about 12 different classes within my app_code folder, would you suggest to use 1 class libraries or one for each class?  thank you

Comment: One class library if you are going to use them together -- no need to get complicated.

Comment: what type of web service would you recommend ? and how would I reference the class library within the web service ?thank you for your time